How to execute a task in Airflow in another server?
I have already set up the following infrastructure:

host (main):
airflow (with all the services)

slave server
airflow (redis, postgres, worker)


Cannot see any tutorial or couldn't find any clue about how to do it, but i don't have any idea about how to connect the task with the parameter queue=node1 to execute it in the slave server, thank you!

You can use the following example to redirect the task:
train_model = PythonOperator(
  task_id='train_model',
  python_callable=train_model_flights
  queue='<QUEUE_NAME>'
)

Also, if you have created this infra using docker-compose, check the airflow-worker section where the "celery worker" command is used. For your new worker with a different queue name, copy and paste this, and change the command to "celery worker -q <QUEUE_NAME>".

could you please add the docker compose of the worker? thank you!

Use https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.9.2/docker-compose.yaml and add airflow-worker-2 referring "airflow-worker" with celery command mentioned above.
